# Mysql performance

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

Which approach is better to do a batch delete in mysql db using jdbc.

I have a list of primary keys. Need to delete them.

1. use batch-update api provided.
2. delete having where clause having in clause.

Comment: Don't know honestly, and i think it's not the overwhelming majority that actually knows this. But this is extremely easy to test, so you could tell us, if you get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use IN in the WHERE clause is faster, as it reduce the data transfer. However there is a trade off, because if the query is too long, *MySQL takes time to parse it*. I suggest that you split it into 10K-length queries if you have too many records to be deleted.

Another solution, is when you have too many records to be deleted, and you get them with another query, you can use directly, for example:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE status = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and decided to benchmark the two approaches using prepared statements and the JDBC driver. My application has 3 (heavily indexed) tables. I have a query to retrieve a list of keys that I need to delete from each table (the key is indexed in all three tables and the primary key in one of them).

First I tried:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE delete_condition
```

With

```
for each delete_id
    DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = delete_id
    DELETE FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = delete_id
    DELETE FROM table3 WHERE table3.id = delete_id
loop
```

I found this offered a delete rate of 74 rows per second.

The second approach:

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE delete_condition)
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE delete_condition)
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.id IN (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE delete_condition)
```

Offered a delete rate of 43,026 rows per second. I'm not sure what's happening under the hood of MySQL, but I'll be using the DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN () approach from now on.